# Javascript double timer

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, settimeout

So i want to set a vanilla JavaScript to display a message screen text for 30-40 seconds then display a different text for 10 seconds. The first message should change in particular order (ie.. hello, world, i ,love java, script). And cycle through. I tried to put it in an a array with a timer but no luck can't get the timer to oscillate between the 30 and 10 seconds. 
So ie... hello for 30 sec, then world for 10 sec, then i love for 30 sec and so on.
Currently I'm following this example but I'd rather not do the math there's got to be a cleaner better way.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

This what i am doing now. Abbreviated

```
function timedText() {
    setTimeout(myTimeout1, 10000) setTimeout(myTimeout2, 30000) setTimeout(myTimeout3, 40000)
}

function myTimeout1() {
    document.getElementById("tebatademo").innerHTML = "<h2 style='background-color: yellow; color: black; text-align: center;'>Mountin Climbers</h2>";
}

function myTimeout2() {
    document.getElementById("tebatademo").innerHTML = "<h2 style='background-color: red; color: white; text-align: center;'>REST</h2>";
}

function myTimeout3() {
    document.getElementById("tebatademo").innerHTML = "<h2 style='background-color: yellow; color: black; text-align: center;'>Inch Worms</h2>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just have two functions, one that sets the other and vice versa?

```
function one() {
  window.alert('Messsage One')
  setTimeout(two, 10*1000);
}

function two() {
  window.alert('Message two');
  setTimeout(one, 30*1000);
}

setTimeout(two, 30*1000);
```

Obviously, you could change the `window.alert` calls to whatever method you're actually using for displaying the text.

EDIT
Ok, to update based on your request.  If you want an array of words to cycle, and varying times, I've done it this way.  Given the HTML:

```
<div id='msgBox'></div>
```

You can setup an array and a function to display from that array like so:

```
var msgBox = document.getElementById('msgBox');
var messages = ['hello', 'world', 'i' ,'love', 'java', 'script']

function updateMessage() {
  // take the first word out of the array and store it in the msg variable
  var msg = messages.shift();
  // set the div content to the word
  msgBox.innerHTML = msg;
  // pick a duration based on if the remaining array length is odd or even
  var duration = messages.length % 2 ? 10 * 1000 : 30 * 1000
  // queue up the next message update
  setTimeout(updateMessage, duration)
}

setTimeout(updateMessage, 10*1000)
```

Obviously, you can tweak the duration bit however you want; I just did a modulo operation so that basically if the array length is even you wait 10 seconds if it's odd you wait 30 seconds.

Likewise if you want to update the inner content to include other information (e.g. like you had an h2 with various styles) you can either put that whole string in the array, or you can use something similar to my duration logic to select the correct wrapper.

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/on78wmj1/)

Comment: I was hoping to use an array one timer after another alerts are a bad example cuz i think they do pause the screen but when i do the txt id thing the timers fire all at once. Thank you for the fast responds

Comment: If you have other requirements, you should put them in the question.  Additionally, it's helpful if you write in whatever code you've tried as it's informative to folks trying to help you as to what you're trying to do.

Comment: @pablo ok, is this closer to what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like below!

> you can modify timeout interval as per your requirement

```js
function myTimeout1() {
    document.getElementById("tebatademo").innerHTML = "<h2 style='background-color: yellow; color: black; text-align: center;'>Mountin Climbers</h2>";
    setTimeout(myTimeout2,3000);
}

function myTimeout2() {
    document.getElementById("tebatademo").innerHTML = "<h2 style='background-color: red; color: white; text-align: center;'>REST</h2>";
    setTimeout(myTimeout3,5000);
}

function myTimeout3() {
    document.getElementById("tebatademo").innerHTML = "<h2 style='background-color: yellow; color: black; text-align: center;'>Inch Worms</h2>";
    setTimeout(myTimeout1,2000);
}
myTimeout1();
```

```html
<div id="tebatademo">
</div>
```

Comment: Dude that is almost perfect thx alot. The only issue is the array does not seem to terminate correctly. It always ends with undefined?

Comment: @pablo glad it helped and please consider accepting answer whenever it helps you. and i don't understand `The only issue is the array does not seem to terminate correctly. It always ends with undefined?` can you please explain bit more ?

Comment: So even in the fiddle the example iterate through the array but towards the end it seems to be infinitely looping without terminating. I've gone through the logic and I can't see where it's going wrong but then again I'm not the greatest JavaScripter. (Getting there)

Comment: Message.shift caused the script to loop forever. Added      if (messages.length > 0){  }    to fix it..... thx for the heavy lifting

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it with OOP.

```js
function Timer(fn, delay) {
  this.startTimer = function(fn, delay) {
    setTimeout(fn, delay);
  }
  return this;
}

function timedText() {
  let timer1 = new Timer();
  let timer2 = new Timer();
  let timer3 = new Timer();
  timer1.startTimer(myTimeout1, 1000);
  timer2.startTimer(myTimeout2, 3000);
  timer2.startTimer(myTimeout3, 4000);
}

function myTimeout1() {
  document.getElementById("tebatademo").innerHTML = "<h2 style='background-color: yellow; color: black; text-align: center;'>Mountin Climbers</h2>";
}

function myTimeout2() {
  document.getElementById("tebatademo").innerHTML = "<h2 style='background-color: red; color: white; text-align: center;'>REST</h2>";
}

function myTimeout3() {
  document.getElementById("tebatademo").innerHTML = "<h2 style='background-color: yellow; color: black; text-align: center;'>Inch Worms</h2>";
}

timedText();
```

```html
<div id="tebatademo"></div>
```

In case if you need to add other functionality of timer in future, you can easily add and remove it not needed anyone.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Paul how it is not? can you please explain?